# How to calculate the proportion of each combination in a data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, combinations

Lets say we have a data.frame as following:

```
  A B C
1 1 1 1
2 1 0 1
3 1 0 1
4 0 1 0
5 0 0 1
```

As Output I want something containing this:

ABC = 0.2

AC = 0.4

B = 0.2

C = 0..2

but for a much larger data.frame. Does anyone know an elegant code to do so?. If so please let me know, thank you.

Comment: How are the proportions being calculated? Why is there no `AB`?

Comment: @d.b Because there's no row `1 1 0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `M` is your matrix you can do

```
table(apply(M, 1, function(v) paste0(names(v[v==1]), collapse = ""))) / nrow(M)
```

With your example:

```
> M <- cbind(A = c(1,1,1,0,0), B = c(1,0,0,1,0), C = c(1,1,1,0,1))
> table(apply(M, 1, function(v) paste0(names(v[v==1]), collapse = ""))) / nrow(M)

ABC  AC   B   C 
0.2 0.4 0.2 0.2
```

Comment: Thank you sir, exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @tacoman You're welcome. If you're satisfied by this answer, please [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

```
ind = which(d == 1, arr.ind = TRUE)
table(sapply(split(colnames(d)[ind[,2]], ind[,1]), paste, collapse = "-"))/NROW(d)

#A-B-C   A-C     B     C 
#  0.2   0.4   0.2   0.2
```

**DATA**

```
d = structure(list(A = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L),
                   B = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L),
                   C = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L)),
              class = "data.frame",
              row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using imap from purr we can replace the 1s with the column name and the 0s with empty strings. Then the prop.table of the columns pasted together gives the desired output

```
library(purrr)

df %>% 
  imap(~ifelse(.x, .y, '')) %>% 
  do.call(what = paste0) %>% 
  table %>% 
  prop.table
# .
# ABC  AC   B   C 
# 0.2 0.4 0.2 0.2
```

If your data is very large it would be faster to change the names of the table at the end instead of creating three new columns of "A", "B" and "C" instead of ones and zeros first. Same output as above, purrr not needed.

```
out <- 
  df %>% 
    do.call(what = paste0) %>% 
    table %>% 
    prop.table

names(out) <- sapply(strsplit(names(out), ''), 
                     function(x) paste(LETTERS[which(x == '1')], collapse = ''))
out
```